# чем отличается :: от -> в php

Tags: php

При вызове функция из класса всегда использовал такую запись: 
`new Class -> function ()`, но недавно увидел это: `Class :: function()`. В чём разница, и в каких случаях что использовать ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` подразумевает обращение к свойству/методу/константе класса в контексте класса (обычно статические свойства/методы и константы классов). Т.е. не обязательно создавать объект, можно обратиться так

```
ClassName::CONSTANTA;
ClassName::method();
```

Но можно и через объект:

```
$o = new ClassName();
$o::CONSTANTA; // обращение в контексте класса через объект.
```

Так же через двоеточие можно обратиться к нестатическим методам, например, родительского класса. Пусть в классе `A` объявлен метод `m()`, тогда внутри класса `B`, который наследуется от `A`, можно обратиться так:

```
parent::m(); //или вообще уточняя A::m();
```

будет вызван метод определенный в родителе.

`->` - подразумевает обращение к свойству/методу класса в контексте объекта. Т.е. обращение должно идти через объект:

```
$o = new ClassName();
$o->method();
$o->param;
```

Answer (score 4):

Разница в вызове метода экземпляра и статическоого метода класса.

```
new Class->method() // Это мы создали экземпляр класса и вызвали его метод
Class::function() // Это мы вызвали статический метод
```

Также [двойное двоеточие](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) позволяет обращаться к статическим свойствам и константам класса.

Answer (score 4):

Дополню немного предыдущих ответчиков.

Парадигма ООП подразумевает у объекта наличие состояния - грубо говоря, значений свойств - и поведения - методов. В ряде случаев в программе появляется функционал и данные, к конкретным объектам не привязанные: например, значение числа пи будет для всех объектов одинаковым, а преобразование Фурье для волны не будет зависеть от состояния объекта, на котором вызывается (т.е. обычная математическая функция, так или иначе реализованная в программе, не зависит от внешних факторов). Для всего этого функционала языки реализуют такие вещи, как константы классов, статические переменные и статические методы. Их ключевое отличие в том, что если обычное свойство или метод привязано к конкретному экземпляру класса, то статическое свойство или метод привязаны к самому классу, и им не нужен экземпляр класса для их чтения / установки или вызова.

Оператор двоеточия же называется в PHP [*оператором разрешения области видимости*](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). Из-за общего отсутствия единообразия в PHP он выполняет смешанные функции, главная из которых - это действительно обращение к статическим свойствам. Но, как выше написал @A1essandro, с его помощью также можно *использовать область видимости* родительских классов - поэтому его область действия чуть шире, чем доступ к статике и константам, и поэтому он не *обеспечивает доступ к статике*, а *разрешает область видимости*.